# FCFS and SRT Processor Algorithm Calculations

Tags: java, algorithm, operating-system, processor, throughput

I have a job queue with 500 jobs that has a String jobName, int arrivalTime, int cpuTime, and String pageFaults (which for the pageFaults it look like this in the file ... ""12, 25, 100, 120"" and it's being read in as a String). And I have to calculate the following...

1)Throughput = ?

2)Average Waiting Time = startTime - arrivalTime

3) Average Turnaround Time = cpuTime + waitingTime + finishTime - arrivalTime

4) CPU Idle Time = ?

-startTime = ?

-finishTime = ?

What's the calculation for throughput, CPU Idle time, startTime and finishTime?

Are my average waiting time and average turnaround time calculations correct?

Also, how do I go about coding these calculations?

And these are done using the First Come First Serve and Shortest Remaining Time algorithms.

Here's what I have so far,

First class:

I've started iterating through the ArrayList and coding a portion of the calculations but that's as far as I can get.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TextFile
 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
   double startTime = (0.0);
   double finishTime = (0.0);

   //double throughput = (0.0);
   double waitingTime = (0.0);
   double turnaroundTime = (0.0);
   //double cpuIdleTime = (0.0);

   String jobName = " ";
   int arrivalTime = (0);
   int cpuTime = (0);
   String pageFault = " ";

   //DataObject object = new DataObject(jobName, arrivalTime, cpuTime, pageFault);

   Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("JobQueue.txt"));

   ArrayList<DataObject> list = new ArrayList<DataObject>(); 

   while(input.hasNext())
    {
     jobName = input.next();
     arrivalTime = input.nextInt();
     cpuTime = input.nextInt();
     pageFault = input.next();

     DataObject data = new DataObject(jobName, arrivalTime, cpuTime, pageFault);
     list.add(data);
    }

   //Calculations for FCFS

    for (DataObject data : list)
    {
     startTime =

     finishTime =

     waitingTime = startTime - arrivalTime;

     turnaroundTime = cpuTime + waitingTime + finishTime - arrivalTime;


    }// compute throughput, average waiting time, etc

   System.out.print(list);//Test output to ensure array list is working

   System.out.printf("%.2f\n", turnaroundTime);

   // compute throughput, average waiting time, etc...
   input.close();
   }
  }
```

Second class:

```
public class DataObject
{
 private String jobName;
 private int arrivalTime;
 private int cpuTime;
 private String pageFault;

 public DataObject(String job, int arrival, int cpu, String interrupt)
 {
  jobName = job;
  arrivalTime = arrival;
  cpuTime = cpu;
  pageFault = interrupt;
 }

 public void setjobName(String job)
 {
  jobName = job;
 }

 public String getJobName()
 {
  return jobName;
 }

 public void setArrivalTime(int arrival)
 {
  arrivalTime = arrival;
 }

 public int getArrivalTime()
 {
  return arrivalTime;
 }

 public void setcpuTime(int cpu)
 {
  cpuTime = cpu;
 }

 public int getcpuTime()
 {
  return cpuTime;
 }

 public void setPageFault(String interrupt)
 {
  pageFault = interrupt;
 }

 public String getPageFault()
 {
  return pageFault;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
  return String.format("\n%s %d %d %s\n", getJobName(), getArrivalTime(), getcpuTime(), getPageFault()); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The throughput of the system is :
**Throughput** = Number of processes completed / (time unit).
What i mean by time unit is the time required to complete the Number of processes in the numerator.

**CPU Idle time** is easy to understand and as it says it is the time for which the CPU remains idle i.e. is not performing any tasks. Ex. A process finished completion at time t and a new process came in at t+4 , thus the CPU remained idle for the time in between.

**Start Time** is the time when the execution of the process begins in the CPU and is not the arrival time of the process.

**Finish Time** execution of the complete process is over.

**Wait time**              - Average time a process spends in the run queue.
For the **Waiting Time** you have considered the `waiting time as the start time - arrival time`. This is correct in the procedures you are using that is the FCFS and the Shortest remaining time first(considering no time slicing)

Sometimes time slicing is used and the processes are addressed in a round robin fashion giving fixed processor time slice to each. So using the formula `Waiting time = Finish time -  Arrival time - CPU time` seems more full proof, and is applicable to your method too.

**Turnaround Time**    - Average time elapsed from when process is submitted to when it has completed. You can calculate this easily using    `Turnaround time = finish time - start time`

If you need the average values, it is as simple as calculating for each of the process and then dividing the sum by number of processes(simple average)

Here is a link where the algorithms to all the methods are given. Check http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/class/05s-osp/notes/notes5.html
to get a good start in your coding:-)